# Is there any remote GUI for ffmpeg?

Tags: software-rec, ffmpeg

I'm looking for some software with both Linux and Windows versions that can remotely run FFMPEG commands on my Linux server. Just like what [transmisson-remote-gui](http://code.google.com/p/transmisson-remote-gui/) does for Transmission.

In summary, I want to be able to convert some videos on my Linux server remotely from my Linux/Windows laptop using a graphical interface. Is this possible?